# How do you select a point using the API as the primary point selection?

Tags: python, mesh, select

I've run into some difficult selecting a point as the "primary selection" (not sure if this is proper terminology)

I've been using this function to select a single point from a mesh:

```
def select_append_point(index):
    #getting proper mode for selection (its object, this is counter intuitive) 
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    #selecting point from index number
    cube_ob.data.vertices[index].select = True
    #note I show how cube_ob is defined below

    #returning to edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

This results in a selection like this:

[image]

it is orange in the viewport, therefore not a primary selection

I'd prefer a selection like this:

[image]

It is white in the viewport and a primary selection.

This is for the application of using the following code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select(edge_mode='SELECT')
```

that code outputs this between two selected points:

[image]

But does not work as intended for an appending application unless one of the points is white not orange.

Thank you for any help!!!

How cube_ob is defined:

```
cube_ob = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube_ob
cube_ob.select_set(state=True)
```